# Basic Auth Headers With React And IIS

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-mvc, http, iis, basic-authentication

We have a React App which is hosted inside an ASP.NET Core site hosted on an IIS Server.

Originally we had the React App hosted on its own in IIS and protected by HTTP Basic Auth on our Staging server. This worked fine.

We then moved to hosting the React App inside the ASP.NET Core site. This has now caused problems with Basic Auth. If the user enters the site through just the domain they can authenticate with Basic Auth and everything works. However is the user refresh a page in their browser, the Basic Auth header is no longer sent and causes the server to challenge the user again for their username and password. For our testers this makes their lives very hard.

We have reproduced this in both Firefox and Chrome.

Using Fiddler we are able to request the pages/documents directly with the Basic Auth header, so we know that direct access is possible. We just don't understand why the browser is removing the header on a refresh.

Answer (score 0):

IIS basic authentication is not cookie-based authentication. client just send user credential to client side with authorization header.  It looks like the fresh page action will clean the cache or override that header. Please check this on other web browser like edge or IE.